# why is my function is only outputing 3 times instead of 5

Tags: javascript

So Im making a project for fun and to develop my Js skills, but I hit a wall, because I cant figure out why it isnt calculating for my last two values and only the first 3, meaning testNumber4 and 5 and testPrice4 and 5. The thing is when Im not calling the function the `console.log("1")` outputs 5 times when I call the function it outputs the 1 only three times. Im not extremely knowledgeable about Js and would appreciate every help aswell other advices to make my code perform or rather be better structered.

My Js Code:

```js
const testNumber1 = 1700494030000;
const testNumber2 = 1700494060000;
const testNumber3 = 1700494090000;
const testNumber4 = 1700494094000;
const testNumber5 = 1700494095000;
const testPrice1 = 100;
const testPrice2 = 200;
const testPrice3 = 300;
const testPrice4 = 310;
const testPrice5 = 320;

let KlineCloseTimeArray = [];
let KlineOpenTimeArray = [];
let klineDataArray = [];

let TestNumberArray = [testNumber1, testNumber2, testNumber3, testNumber4, testNumber5];
let TestPriceArray = [testPrice1, testPrice2, testPrice3, testPrice4, testPrice5];

let combinedArray = TestNumberArray.map((testNumber, index) => {
  return {
    e: testNumber,
    c: TestPriceArray[index]
  };
});

// Function to create Kline data
function createKlineData(Time, openTime, closeTime, closePrice) {
  return {
    "E": Time,
    "k": {
      "t": openTime,
      "T": closeTime,
      "s": "BTCUSDT",
      "i": "1m",
      "o": "testing", //openPrice.toString(),
      "c": closePrice.toString(),
    },
  };
};
// Calculation to determin the t and T value open CandleStick value and close CandelStick value
// Function to calculate open and close times
function calculateKlineTimes(currentTestNumber, currentTestPrice) {
  let KlineOpenTime = null;
  let KlineCloseTime = null;

  // Check downwards
  for (let i = currentTestNumber - 10000; i >= 0; i -= 10000) {
    if (i % 60000 === 0) {
      KlineOpenTime = i;
      break;
    }
  };

  // Check upwards
  for (let i = currentTestNumber + 10000;; i += 10000) {
    if (i % 60000 === 0) {
      KlineCloseTime = +i - 1;
      break;
    }
  };
  if (klineDataArray.length > 0) {
    LastKlineDataArray = klineDataArray[klineDataArray.length - 1];
    console.log(LastKlineDataArray)
    console.log("testing")
  };

  KlineCloseTimeArray.push(KlineCloseTime);
  KlineOpenTimeArray.push(KlineOpenTime);
  if (klineDataArray.length > 0) {
    if (KlineOpenTime > LastKlineDataArray.k.t) {
      klineDataArray.push(createKlineData(currentTestNumber, LastKlineDataArray.k.t, LastKlineDataArray.k.T, currentTestPrice));
    }
  };
  // Create Kline data and print it
  const klineData = createKlineData(currentTestNumber, KlineOpenTime, KlineCloseTime, currentTestPrice);
  console.log(klineData)
  klineDataArray.push(klineData);
  //console.log(JSON.stringify(klineData, null, 2));
  //console.log(klineDataArray);
  console.log("::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::");
}

// Calculate Kline times for each combined test number and price
for (let item of combinedArray) {
  calculateKlineTimes(item.e, item.c);
  console.log("1")
}

console.log("Minimum Requirement Array:", KlineOpenTimeArray);
console.log("Maximum Requirement Array:", KlineCloseTimeArray);
```

so I tried to look at the amount `console.log("1")` is putting out without calling the function before, which is 5 times. When calling the function the 1 appears only 3 times in the console.
Of course I tried also changing the code but that didnt quite solve the problem and this one looks a bit cleaner then my other attempts.

Comment: It seems to be getting stuck in a loop after the third `1`.

Comment: I think one of the `for`-loops never reaches its `break` command, and therefore loops forever, most likely the 2nd one because it has no built-in exit condition.

Comment: On the 4th iteration, `currentTestNumber` is `1700494094000`. The loop that checks upward never stops because it's never a multiple of `60000`.

Comment: I have no idea what this code is supposed to be doing (I don't know what Kline means), so I have no suggestion for how to fix it.

Comment: You'll have the same problem with `const testNumber5 = 1700494095000;`. The "check upwards" code only works if the test number is a multiple of 10,000.

Comment: Thank you guys, that was the problem I just changed it to so now it wont get stuck by going down 10000 or up since my input values will always be a full number it will come across a division with 60000 when I just add or subtract 1 from my value.

`  for (let i = currentTestNumber - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
    if (i % 60000 === 0) {
      KlineOpenTime = i;
      break;
    }
  };

  // Check upwards
  for (let i = currentTestNumber + 1; ; i += 1) {
    if (i % 60000 === 0) {
      KlineCloseTime = +i - 1;
      break;
    }
  };`

Comment: you don't have to run the loops at all if the number `% 10000 !== 0` - because maths

Comment: are you sure since this is using just some test values in the actual usage i will be using values from an api and those are always like ...4568 representing a timestamp thats why i want to calculate each minute stamp but i only came up with the solution to test values up and down till its divisable by 60000 to make a minute start and end timestamp.